# How to add SYLT tags to a mp3 file?

Tags: python, mp3, mutagen

I want to add synchronized lyrics to songs in mp3 format. I am using the mutagen module for doing so. While i can add unsynchronized lyrics without any problem, I can't seem to get SYLT working. Here is the code

```
aud = ID3("C:\\Music\\Ghost.mp3")
aud.add(SYLT(encoding=Encoding.UTF8, format=2, type=1, text=sl))
aud.save()
```

Where "sl" is a list of the format as shown below

```
sl = [("lyric", millisecond), ("lyric", millisecond), ("lyric", millisecond)]
```

Can anyone please guide me with this problem? I would be extremely grateful if somebody can lead me in the right direction. Your explanation need not be in python. Please feel free to explain in any language you are comfortable with. Thank you in advance.

PS: Sorry for bad english. It isn't my native.

Comment: Hi Ram, did you check for other results? like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61166697/1896134 did this not help?

Comment: Thank you Jay for your reply. I did check it out and in fact it was from that post I learned how to use SYLT. And it all works fine. But the problem is Samsung music doesn't recognise it. Now that I think about it, it seems that the problem is with the player itself than the method. It seems that most players are compatible with only lrc files.

Comment: Hi Ram, I am wondering if it is due to maybe the tag version: maybe try using an a different tag version. depicted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25950392/1896134

Answer (score 0):

I got this figured out from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61166697/1896134) and turns out it stores the placement in MilliSeconds (1 second = 1000 ms).

Here is a basic example of how:

```py
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, SYLT, Encoding

filename = '/Users/JayRizzo/Music/Tom MacDonald - Angels (Explicit).mp3'
tag = ID3(filename)
sync_lrc = [
    ("It's not the liquor I'm addicted to, it's feeling brave",                                          1000),
    ("The feeling of not feeling the pain",                                                              2000),
    ("I been on and off the bottle, I put oxys up my nostrils, believe me",                              3000),
    ("You do anything to breathe before you suffocate",                                                  4000),
    ("I couldn't stop it, staying clean was not an option",                                              5000),
    ("I was tryna be myself but being me was such a problem",                                            6000),
    ("I just wanted to be Thomas, but Thomas was at the bottom of a hole he dug",                        7000),
    ("And getting comfortable inside a coffin, ay",                                                      8000),
    ("He locked it and swallowed the key, he caught up, forgot all his dreams",                          9000),
    ("Robbed outta calm and became embalmed in a toxic routine",                                        10000),
    ("Beer was the escape but I got stuck escaping",                                                    11000),
    ("Whiskey was the blanket in the coldest basement",                                                 12000),
    ("Way before the fame, I was wasted",                                                               13000),
    ("Freezing, doing anything I could to keep the flame lit",                                          14000),
    ("To anyone going through the same shit",                                                           15000),
    ("Heaven's got enough angels, you need to stay here",                                               16000),
    ("And I can't make you stay but sometimes going ain't a choice",                                    17000),
    ("And every choice you make is one that you didn't avoid",                                          18000),
    ("Crash the whip and ditch the car, burn a bridge, follow the stars",                               19000),
    ("You'll find monsters in the dark but nothing's worth it till it's hard",                          20000),
    ("Sometimes it's hard to see things clear (through your tears)",                                    21000),
    ("But anywhere is way better than here (fight your fears)",                                         22000),
    ("It's not the liquor I'm addicted to, it's feeling tough",                                         23000),
    ("When you get bullied half your life you feel weak like you just ain't enough",                    24000),
    ("Then you have a couple drinks and you catch a buzz",                                              25000),
    ("And finally have the courage to defend yourself and throw a punch",                               26000),
    ("And that adrenaline goes straight into your brain and blood",                                     27000),
    ("Addicted to the confidence, it's practically the greatest drug",                                  28000),
    ("Chasing dragons every night in all the latest clubs",                                             29000),
    ("What used to be your favorite thing somehow became a dangerous crutch",                           30000),
    ("It was what it was",                                                                              31000),
    ("And that's the thing, it can happen to like any of us",                                           32000),
    ("I had great parents, tight friends, strong walls, nice threads",                                  33000),
    ("Good school, good looking, good grades, time spent",                                              34000),
    ("Being normal only lasted for a while",                                                            35000),
    ("One bad choice sparked a downward spiral",                                                        36000),
    ("I've spent half my life tryna climb outta that hole",                                             37000),
    ("Heaven's got angels, we need you at home",                                                        38000),
    ("And I can't make you stay but sometimes going ain't a choice",                                    39000),
    ("And every choice you make is one that you didn't avoid",                                          40000),
    ("Crash the whip and ditch the car, burn a bridge, follow the stars",                               41000),
    ("You'll find monsters in the dark but nothing's worth it till it's hard",                          42000),
    ("Sometimes it's hard to see things clear (through your tears)",                                    43000),
    ("But anywhere is way better than here (fight your fears)",                                         44000),
    ("It ain't the liquor we're addicted to, it's everything else",                                     45000),
    ("The happiness we had but we forget how it felt",                                                  46000),
    ("We been drinking with the devil 'cause we're going through hell",                                 47000),
    ("Pray to God for a little bit of help",                                                            48000),
    ("Man, I been there, I did those things, I drank those drinks",                                     49000),
    ("I took those pills, I puked in sinks",                                                            50000),
    ("And the truth ain't pretty, listen up, it's a tough one",                                         51000),
    ("You get saved by your angels or become one",                                                      52000),
    ("Crash the whip and ditch the car, burn a bridge, follow the stars",                               53000),
    ("You'll find monsters in the dark but nothing's worth it till it's hard",                          54000),
    ("Sometimes it's hard to see things clear (through your tears)",                                    55000),
    ("But anywhere is way better than here (fight your fears)",                                         56000)
]
tag.setall("SYLT", [SYLT(encoding=Encoding.UTF8, lang='eng', format=2, type=1, text=sync_lrc)])
tag.save(v2_version=4)

print(tag.get('SYLT::eng'))
```

#### Returns the following:

```py
# [1000ms]: It's not the liquor I'm addicted to, it's feeling brave
# [2000ms]: The feeling of not feeling the pain
# [3000ms]: I been on and off the bottle, I put oxys up my nostrils, believe me
# [4000ms]: You do anything to breathe before you suffocate
# [5000ms]: I couldn't stop it, staying clean was not an option
# [6000ms]: I was tryna be myself but being me was such a problem
# [7000ms]: I just wanted to be Thomas, but Thomas was at the bottom of a hole he dug
# [8000ms]: And getting comfortable inside a coffin, ay
# [9000ms]: He locked it and swallowed the key, he caught up, forgot all his dreams
# [10000ms]: Robbed outta calm and became embalmed in a toxic routine
# [11000ms]: Beer was the escape but I got stuck escaping
# [12000ms]: Whiskey was the blanket in the coldest basement
# [13000ms]: Way before the fame, I was wasted
# [14000ms]: Freezing, doing anything I could to keep the flame lit
# [15000ms]: To anyone going through the same shit
# [16000ms]: Heaven's got enough angels, you need to stay here
# [17000ms]: And I can't make you stay but sometimes going ain't a choice
# [18000ms]: And every choice you make is one that you didn't avoid
# [19000ms]: Crash the whip and ditch the car, burn a bridge, follow the stars
# [20000ms]: You'll find monsters in the dark but nothing's worth it till it's hard
# [21000ms]: Sometimes it's hard to see things clear (through your tears)
# [22000ms]: But anywhere is way better than here (fight your fears)
# [23000ms]: It's not the liquor I'm addicted to, it's feeling tough
# [24000ms]: When you get bullied half your life you feel weak like you just ain't enough
# [25000ms]: Then you have a couple drinks and you catch a buzz
# [26000ms]: And finally have the courage to defend yourself and throw a punch
# [27000ms]: And that adrenaline goes straight into your brain and blood
# [28000ms]: Addicted to the confidence, it's practically the greatest drug
# [29000ms]: Chasing dragons every night in all the latest clubs
# [30000ms]: What used to be your favorite thing somehow became a dangerous crutch
# [31000ms]: It was what it was
# [32000ms]: And that's the thing, it can happen to like any of us
# [33000ms]: I had great parents, tight friends, strong walls, nice threads
# [34000ms]: Good school, good looking, good grades, time spent
# [35000ms]: Being normal only lasted for a while
# [36000ms]: One bad choice sparked a downward spiral
# [37000ms]: I've spent half my life tryna climb outta that hole
# [38000ms]: Heaven's got angels, we need you at home
# [39000ms]: And I can't make you stay but sometimes going ain't a choice
# [40000ms]: And every choice you make is one that you didn't avoid
# [41000ms]: Crash the whip and ditch the car, burn a bridge, follow the stars
# [42000ms]: You'll find monsters in the dark but nothing's worth it till it's hard
# [43000ms]: Sometimes it's hard to see things clear (through your tears)
# [44000ms]: But anywhere is way better than here (fight your fears)
# [45000ms]: It ain't the liquor we're addicted to, it's everything else
# [46000ms]: The happiness we had but we forget how it felt
# [47000ms]: We been drinking with the devil 'cause we're going through hell
# [48000ms]: Pray to God for a little bit of help
# [49000ms]: Man, I been there, I did those things, I drank those drinks
# [50000ms]: I took those pills, I puked in sinks
# [51000ms]: And the truth ain't pretty, listen up, it's a tough one
# [52000ms]: You get saved by your angels or become one
# [53000ms]: Crash the whip and ditch the car, burn a bridge, follow the stars
# [54000ms]: You'll find monsters in the dark but nothing's worth it till it's hard
# [55000ms]: Sometimes it's hard to see things clear (through your tears)
# [56000ms]: But anywhere is way better than here (fight your fears)
```

Doesn't seem to show up in iTunes, QuickTime, or VLC that I can tell so far.